# How to creat List<Class<Exception>>

Tags: java

I need to create `List<Class<Exception>>`. What I already tried:

```java
    List<Class<Exception>> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(NullPointerException.class);//not allowed. IDE suggests to change list type to 
                                         //List<Class<NullPoninteException>>
    list.add(Exception.class);
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Not sure why the IDE gives an error. But you definitely should avoid the **raw** type. Use `new ArrayList<>()` instead of leaving out the generic type completely. Maybe the raw type confuses your IDE.

Comment: And as you are asking about a problem with your IDE: add the relevant details to your question, like what IDE; and version.

Comment: What you want is a `List<Class<? extends Exception>>`: A list of classes, each of which extends Exception. If it was a `List<Class<Exception>>` it could only contain `Exception.class`.

Comment: Well, `Class<Exception>` states the _exact_ type of elements and `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `Exception` and not the exact type `Exception.class`. Try using `Class<? extends Exception>`.

Comment: Yes. This one works for me: `List<Class<? extends Exception>>` in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException.class` is not a `Class<Exception>`. It is a `Class<NullPointerException>`. Different.

What you want is a `List<Class<? extends Exception>>`: A list of classes, each of which extends Exception. If it was a `List<Class<Exception>>` it could only contain `Exception.class`.